# Accessing WiFi printer on a 2nd WiFi network which is connected to 1st WiFi network via Ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, printer

I've been trying to work out the setup below (see image) where I've got a main WiFi router / modem combination in one part of a house and then a Ethernet cable going to another point in the house which is where I have a second WiFi router.

Connected to this second WiFi router is a WiFi printer. Is there some way that I would be able to access the WiFi printer whilst being connected to the 1st network wirelessly via my laptop?

[image: diagram]

Comment: Is there any reason to have two _separate_ Wifi networks in the first place? Why not just have two APs for the same network?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a WiFi extender and connect the printer to the WiFi extender to the 1<sup>st</sup> router(as shown below):

[image]

I think you should use a WiFi extender to connect the the other part of your house and not use a 2<sup>nd</sup> router.

Comment: The router would be just fine as long as the "routing" part was disabled.

Comment: You can also use port fowarding.